# LINQ left join with only the row having maximum value of a column

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq

I have a table **ProjectInformation** as (left table)

```
ProjectID int
{fields}
```

the other table, **ProjectUpdates** (right table). This table has multiple record for 1 ProjectID added monthly.

```
ProjectID int
CreateDate date
{other fields that have records}
```

Their relation is 1-M. 
Sample Data

```
ProjectInformation
{ ProjectID = 1, DataA = "ABC"}
{ ProjectID = 2, DataA = "DEF"}
{ ProjectID = 3, DataA = "GHI"}

ProjectUpdates
{ProjectID = 1, CreateDate = "24/2/2014", DataB = "JKL"}
{ProjectID = 1, CreateDate = "25/1/2014", DataB = "MNL"}
{ProjectID = 1, CreateDate = "23/12/2014", DataB = "PQR"}
{ProjectID = 1, CreateDate = "23/11/2014", DataB = "STU"}
{ProjectID = 2, CreateDate = "24/2/2014", DataB = "VWX"}
{ProjectID = 2, CreateDate = "24/1/2014", DataB = "YZA"}
{ProjectID = 3, CreateDate = "21/12/2014", DataB = "BCD"}
{ProjectID = 3, CreateDate = "24/11/2014", DataB = "EFG"}
{ProjectID = 3, CreateDate = "24/10/2014", DataB = "HIJ"}
{ProjectID = 3, CreateDate = "24/8/2014", DataB = "KLM"}
{ProjectID = 3, CreateDate = "24/6/2014", DataB = "NOP"}
```

I want my LINQ query to return the following Data (1 row for each project)

Criteria: The row in left table will join with the one in the right which has the largest value of **CreateDate** for the project.

```
{ProjectID = 1, CreateDate = "24/2/2014", DataA ="ABC", DataB = "JKL"}
{ProjectID = 2, CreateDate = "24/2/2014", DataA ="DEF", DataB = "VWX"}
{ProjectID = 3, CreateDate = "21/12/2014", DataA ="GHI", DataB = "BCD"}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to show different projects ids in resulting dataset. Btw, have you tried anything?

Comment: FYI: Your example output all has the same `ProjectID` of `1`. It should be `1 2 & 3`.

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui - Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it many ways. One of those way is:

```
var result = (from pi in projectInformations
              join pu in projectUpdates on pi.ProjectID equals pu.ProjectID into tpu
              from t in tpu.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate).Take(1)
              select new { pi.ProjectID, pi.DataA, t.CreateDate, t.DataB }).ToList();
```

Comment: I was just coming to a very close solution, anyway here's the test code I was using http://rextester.com/KLPBI85561

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [one to many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) association from ProjectInformation to ProjectUpdate and OrderByDescending/FirstOrDefault.

```
public class ProjectInformation {
  public int ProjectID { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ProjectUpdate> ProjectUpdates { get; set; }
}

db.Project
  .Select(p => new {
    ProjectID = p.ProjectID,
    MostRecentProjectUpdate = p.ProjectUpdates.OrderByDescending(u => u.CreateDate).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

*Note: Using OrderByDescending may be tricky if CreateDate is a string rather than a Date in your database.*

Comment: The entity or complex type ' ' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. My Query

var projects = from p in _context.PROJECTINFORMATION
                           where p.ISACTIVE == "Y"
                select new PROJECTINFORMATION()
                {
                    PROJECTID = p.PROJECTID,
                    PROJECTSUMMARYUPDATES = (ICollection<PROJECTSUMMARYUPDATES>)p.PROJECTSUMMARYUPDATES.OrderByDescending(x => x.UPDATEFORMONTH).FirstOrDefault()
                    
                };
            return projects.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var result = (from pi in projectInfo
              join pu in projectupdates
              on pi.ProjectID equals pu.ProjectID into g
              let data = g.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.CreateDate, 
                           "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).FirstOrDefault()
              select new
              {
                  ProjectID = data.ProjectID,
                  CreatedDate = data.CreateDate,
                  DataA = pi.DataA,
                  DataB = data.DataB
               }).ToList();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VF5Qm6).

Please note, Since I am using `FirstOrDefault` you need to check if data is not null before accessing its properties.